# Unable to install Evolution on Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, evolution, dependencies

I had evolution 3.2.3 working on Xubuntu 12.04. But then I was tempted to upgrade my evolution to the latest and greatest so I did a bit of searching and added the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:janvitus/gnomestracciatella
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

but that failed so I removed the PPA and tried to install the default evolution

```
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

but that fails too with following output

```
evolution : Depends: libevolution (< 3.3) but 3.4.2-1ubuntu3.1~stracciatellappa+precise1 is to be installed
             Depends: evolution-data-server (< 3.3) but 3.4.2-1~stracciatellappa+precise1 is to be installed
             Recommends: evolution-plugins but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anybody help me fix the issue and install evolution? We have MS Outlook at work and I really need to get it working.

Comment: Why did you want to install from that PPA and not just the one from the main Ubuntu repositories? Also, you could try running `sudo apt-get install evolution -f` to attempt to fix the broken packages.

Comment: I tried the janvitus ppa because evolution 3.4.x was only available from that ppa.
And `sudo apt-get install evolution -f` does not work, i get the same result as before